# Cairo memory leak on draw

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, cairo

I've written a drawCircle function below but as more circles are drawn/redrawn, memory usage increases greatly, so I'm assuming theres a memory leak somewhere but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried deleting the instance at the end of the function but that doesn't help.

```
void drawCircle(cairo_surface_t *container, int x, int y, int radius, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{   
cairo_t *cairoInstance;                                                                                                                      
cairoInstance = cairo_create(container);                                                                                                                     

cairo_set_source_rgba(cairoInstance, r, g, b, a);
cairo_arc(cairoInstance, x, y, radius, 0, 2*M_PI);
cairo_stroke_preserve(cairoInstance);
cairo_fill_preserve(cairoInstance);

//delete cairoInstance;
gtk_widget_queue_draw_area(GTK_WIDGET(frame2), 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);   
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use valgrind to determine the origin of memory leaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points:

- `cairo_t`s are reference counted. Call [`cairo_destroy`](http://maemo.org/api_refs/4.0/cairo/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-destroy) when you are done with your `cairo_t*`. Alternatively, you don't need to create and destroy `cairo_t`'s for each circle - refactor the function by pulling out the call to `cairo_create`.
- Unless you need them, prefer the `cairo_X` functions to the `cairo_X_preserve` ones. In your code `cairo_fill_preserve` should probably be `cairo_preserve`. (The stroke should be preserved though, so that the following fill works.)
- The call to invalidate a rectangle of your gtk widget with `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area` can be refactored out as well, and only done once per draw.
- `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area` invalidates a rectangular region of the widgets window - you may be fine with just `gdk_window_invalidate_rect` - see [the documentation](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw-area)

Psuedo-code after refactoring (with a hypothetical Circle type):

```
void drawCircle(cairo_t *cr, int x, int y, int radius, float r, float g, float b, float a) {   
    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, r, g, b, a);
    cairo_arc(cr, x, y, radius, 0, 2*M_PI);
    cairo_stroke_preserve(cr); // keep the arc so that we can call cairo_fill
    cairo_fill(cr);
}

void functionThatDrawsCircles(cairo_surface_t* surface, Circle* circles, int num) {
    cairo_t* cr = cairo_create(surface);
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        drawCircle(cr, circles[i].x, circles[i].y, 10, circles[i].r, circles[i].g, circles[i].b, 1.0);
    }
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    gtk_widget_queue_draw_area(GTK_WIDGET(frame2), 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);   
}
```

Comment: Tried that earlier, looks like it has no effect.

Comment: You should probably also be calling `cairo_fill` instead of `cairo_fill_preserve` unless you need that arc path after calling drawCircle. Also, `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area` consumes memory per call until the main loop becomes idle, so if you probably don't want to be creating invalidation rectangles in drawCircle (move it outside, and only call it once per frame/update etc.)

Comment: Done that, I think it saves some memory but should the program use 500+ MB of RAM after 15 redraws?

Comment: Ok, so after further testing, turns out gtk_widget_queue_draw_area(GTK_WIDGET(frame2), 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT); was taking a lot of memory. I've replaced it with gtk_widget_queue_draw_area which still takes a lot but not as much. I wonder why it takes this amount of memory and not freeing it after the redraw.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more info from these comments. Sorry, which function did you replace it with? (You said gtk_widget_queue_draw_area twice..) One way this could cause memory to usage to skyrocket would be if you were calling that function in a loop many many times (much more than 15) without letting the gtk app go to idle. If you are running your draw function in a loop to try to see memory growth/"leakage" this may be it. Try using valgrind to find out what exactly is being leaked if anything.

Comment: lol, turns out I replaced gtk_widget_queue_draw_area with itself.

Anyway, Turns out the memory leak was cause by a cairo_t* not being destroyed. (It was created on the draw event). 

Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it :)